# C++ Binary search tree compare data of nodes and remove duplicates

Tags: c++, tree, text-files, duplicates

I have created a binary search tree in c++ and have loaded it up with two types of data, strings and ints.  I am reading a text file and loading the tree up alphabetically with the words I am pulling, and also the number of the line the word is found on.  I am able to print the words and the numbers just fine.  What I am wanting to do now is check to see if a word has already been printed, and if it has then I will only print out the number of the line from which the word is found on.  The way I am thinking about doing this is by comparing previous data as the tree is traversed and printed.  This is my print function.

```
void inOrderPrint(Node *rootPtr ) {
    if ( rootPtr != NULL ) {
        for (int i =0; rootPtr->data[i]; i++){
            while(ispunct(rootPtr->data[i]))
                rootPtr->data.erase(i,1);
                }
        rootPtr->data = rootPtr->data.substr(0,10);
        inOrderPrint( rootPtr->left );
        cout << (rootPtr->data)<<rootPtr->lineNum <<endl;
        inOrderPrint( rootPtr->right );
    }
}
```

This is what I was thinking:

```
if (rootPtr->data == previous rootPtr->data)
    cout<<setw(10)<<theCurrentNode lineNum;
else
    do normal printing
```

I think that if this function were to run on the first node and it compares it to the non existent previous node, it would automatically try to compare it to NULL, the if statement would return false and it would move on to the else.

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this with actual c++ syntax?  Or does anyone see a flaw in my logic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm utterly lost on why you're *modifying* data in the tree while enumerating it, but perhaps that was your intent. The `substr` logic, ec, makes no sense to me at all. Punctuation, etc, should be stripped *before* the data is added to the tree. As the tree is built if a word is discovered as previously existing, the current line number should be appended to a line-num container (a `std::set<>` springs to mind) maintained for each word. In the end, each word will be in the tree only once with all line numbers where it is present accounted for. Or I completely misunderstood the assignment.

Comment: I agree, I will modify the data before adding it to the tree.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer will describe how to make the program print unique entries and the line number of the first occurrence in the file. If there are duplicate occurrences it will print only the line number of the first occurrence for each duplicate occurrence. The approach is to make sure that there are no duplicate nodes in the tree and to count redundant occurrences.

To do this we might modify the node structure as follows:

```
struct Node{
    string data;
    int lineNum;
    int count =1;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
```

The function Insert might be edited to count duplicates like this:

```
Node* Insert(Node* rootPtr,string data,int lineNum){
if(rootPtr == NULL){
    rootPtr = GetNewNode(data,lineNum);
    for (int i =0; rootPtr->data[i]; i++){
        while(ispunct(rootPtr->data[i]))
            rootPtr->data.erase(i,1);
            }
    rootPtr->data = rootPtr->data.substr(0,10);

    return rootPtr;
}
else if(data< rootPtr->data){
    rootPtr->left = Insert(rootPtr->left,data,lineNum);
    for (int i =0; rootPtr->data[i]; i++){
        while(ispunct(rootPtr->data[i]))
            rootPtr->data.erase(i,1);
            }
    rootPtr->data = rootPtr->data.substr(0,10);
}
else if(data > rootPtr->data) {
    rootPtr->right = Insert(rootPtr->right,data,lineNum);
    for (int i =0; rootPtr->data[i]; i++){
        while(ispunct(rootPtr->data[i]))
            rootPtr->data.erase(i,1);
            }
    rootPtr->data = rootPtr->data.substr(0,10);

}
else if(data == rootPtr->data)
    ++rootPtr->count;

return rootPtr;
}
```

Finally the print function can be modified:

```
void inOrderPrint(Node *rootPtr ) {
//ofstream outputFile;
//outputFile.open("Output.txt");

if ( rootPtr != NULL ) {
    inOrderPrint( rootPtr->left );
    cout << (rootPtr->data)<<" " << rootPtr->lineNum <<endl;
    int j =rootPtr->count;
    while( --j )
    cout << rootPtr->lineNum <<endl;

    //outputFile << (rootPtr->data)<<rootPtr->lineNum <<endl;
    inOrderPrint( rootPtr->right );
}
}
```

Now this should be much closer to what you want. It would also be a good idea to separate the text processing from the node processing. (This answer sort of assumes that you will take care of that.) Otherwise duplicate nodes will be created if the preprocessed text does not match the processed text.

Good luck!

Comment: I think I am following your logic, but I after adding the code to the print function and editing the node to add printed, nothing has changed.  I am still receiving the same output as I would if I had not changed it at all.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, it is very difficult to help you figure out what is wrong. Also it is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. It would help if you could clarify the problem, including the structure of the input file. Keep in mind that you are recursively calling the print function which might make things more confusing than need be.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy replies @Brad Here is a link to what I am working with: http://ideone.com/uketbt

Comment: Hi @Nick, I checked out your code and it seems like you are creating a new node for each entry. I believe what you want is to create new nodes only when the string does not match one that has already been entered. I will edit my answer based upon this new information.

Comment: thank you for all your help and time!  I really appreciate it.  I ended up finding a better way to go about doing this.  I created a separate list for keeping track of the line numbers.

Comment: That makes sense if you want to keep track of all line numbers. In that case you can make the list a member of the node struct. Then instead of incrementing a count, you simply push the line numbers onto the list.